# Which chargers to buy for a charging station?

Tags: charging, magsafe, charger

To make a charging station effective, it needs to be able to charge all recent Apple laptops. As you know, Apple chargers are not cheap. So, we'd like to buy as few chargers as possible.

Given [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700) article, what would be the most cost effective way to set this up?

I've read online about how higher wattage chargers can be used for lower wattage computers. If we were to buy one Magsafe 1 85 Watt charger and a Magsafe to Magsafe 2 converter, would we be able to charge all apple laptops besides the new Retina Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES.

You can use the higher power Charger on lower power laptops. The battery will only take as much as it can handle.

It is a pull not push process.

Extra info: If you were to use lower power charger on high power laptop, you could end up newer charging the battery fully, or it could take extended time to charge.

Comment: You don't think it would be an issue using the wrong wattage and an adapter? It just makes me nervous that I might destroy somebody else's computer.

Comment: Absolutely not. As said the Battery is in control and it only takes as much as it needs. The charger is not pushing (forcing) it on to the battery. That would not be healthy for the batteries. Just imagine that to be the case, you would be blowing batteries and it is against the safety regulations.